# Shortcuts for web controls and HTML snippets in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-snippets

Consider the feature in Visual Studio 2010 for snippets in the HTML Source view of a web page.

type a control name in plaintext with no markup or brackets!
... e.g. `hyperlink`.

[image]

Then hit Tab

[image]

Your web control has been auto-completed for you. It's up to you to fill in the other details that you need.

This works for `form` as well:

```
 <form action="default.aspx" method="post">
 </form>
```

This looks like a real time saver. This is supported in WebForms and ASP.NET MVC projects.

**What other snippets** are available in Visual Studio 2010 in the Source view of a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the authoritative list of snippets, check out the VS2010 installation folders where the snippets are stored:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Web\Snippets\HTML\1033
```

There is one folder for ASP.NET and one for plain HTML snippets.

Also, if you use jQuery a lot, there is [a set of jQuery snippets](http://jquerysnippets.codeplex.com/) that you can add to Visual Studio as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a ton (100's) of the short cuts in Visual Studio right from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

The one thing that has been around forever but a lot of people forget about is block selection done by holding down the ALT key and use the mouse to select a block of text.  Great when you want to copy/cut/delete a bunch of code that is lined up but you don't want the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a really cool new set of snippets in VS2010. Here are the articles I used to learn it:

1. [Walkthrough: Using HTML
   Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd985242.aspx)
2. [Using HTML Code Snippets in Visual
   Studio 2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/VS2010/ASPNET/WebDevelopment/Exercise-1-Using-HTML-Code-Snippets-in-Visual-Studio-2010/)